# Dealing with questions that show no effort

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, questions

It's not an epidemic yet, but we've had [two questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8638/where-and-how-to-get-copyright-on-document) in [two days](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8616/copyright-my-illustration-art) about [copyright](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) that suggest the asker hasn't read *anything* about the subject.  I mean, if they typed the word into any browser bar and clicked on any result in the first 100 links they would either find their answer or be able to ask a more substantial question.

Many answerers have essentially (and graciously) done a "[Let-me-google-that-for-you](http://lmgtfy.com/)," and provided a synopsis of the first link.  That *might* be the most beneficial thing for this site/community.

Or maybe answerers' time is more valuable, in which case: Should we add a Close Reason along the lines of, "**UTFSE**?"

Or, [as gracey put it more eloquently](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/414/dealing-with-is-x-illegal-questions#comment669_414):

> I think it would be beneficial to set a requisite similar to stack
>   exchange or ask different, where it is incumbent upon the asker to do
>   some modicum of due diligence relating to their Q - like researching
>   the issue at least a bit, before asking the Q.

A *network-wide* close reason along these lines was considered, tested, and [ultimately rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88521/241697), but it is still implemented on some sites, and we are free to do it here.

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the problem is they did UTFSE and it led them here.

Another part is that it is possible to live your entire life without needing *any* understanding of even the most basic legal principles that underlie society; cultural norms and taboos are *way* more effective than the law in guiding behaviour. A person asking a question on Stack Exchange will know *something* about programming in general and their problem in particular; a poster here may not know where to start *at all*.

It is difficult to wrap your head around intellectual property rights if you don't have a clue about personal property rights and how to use the law to defend them from which to start.

I think we can help a bit more by putting links to the basic (Wikipedia) info actually in the tag description - I have just done this for the copyright tag. This probably wont help much though; since no one read these anyway.

I think that it can be left to the community to close these as "too broad" or answer them as they see fit.

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps some answers using a copy/paste of the first few (non-ad) google responses might be acceptable, though they would not be on some other sites.