# Would this be an acceptable question here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> [The question has been posted](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/have-there-ever-been-examples-of-public-schools-restriction-of-community-servic)

I have a question about the legality of my school's community service policy. (Presumably it is legal, but I want to be sure before I go and do a bunch of stuff..

I figured It'd be okay here, but I don't know the rules specifically, so I figured I'd ask first.

---

The question more specifically:

My school has a clause regarding community service done for "religiously affialted organaztions or events" and states that they won't accept service for any of them. Is this legal, (if not) what could I do about it, other than filing a lawsuit against my school?

---

After reading what feetwet said and the sources he provided, I would plan to add some more context or changes

- Rather than asking if it's legal, ask for any examples of it being illegal
- Provide the location of the school (and thus more details on jurisdictions)
- Provide the school's reasoning for disallowing
- Do more research myself (which I might as well do while I wait anyway)

Comment: It's certainly on-topic.  Once you have enough information to formulate it as a good question you should post it.  Comments will alert you to any significant problems.

Comment: The nature of the school – government vs. private – is crucial, in the US. The government must be religiously neutral, but private concerns have no such restriction. The specific issue would be about case law and the question of whether excluding religious activities as opposed to "social justice" activities violates the 1st Amendment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to provide a lot more facts for that to possibly be answered.  E.g., what sort of school is it, what is the nature of the requirement and the exclusion, etc.

It would be great if you also reviewed [Dealing with "Is X (il)legal" questions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/414/10)