# Questions about emerging fields

Tags: discussion

I [asked a question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31016/if-holding-a-photograph-is-permitted-can-a-company-use-facial-recognition) a few days ago about facial recognition which has, so far, received no answers. I suspect the reason for this is that this technology is fairly new and rare (at least in terms of implementation in businesses) and either no specific laws are in place about it or there is no real precedent for an answer.

In cases like this is there a process for reawakening the questions when answers become evident or do we leave them to be asked again later on?

I thought perhaps there may be a tag for questions which can't be answered yet so they're more easily spotted.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your explicit question is no: The only intentional Stack Exchange mechanism for "reawakening" a question is to offer a bounty.

However, my opinion is that the reason that question has received no answers is because the correct answer is simply, "No law requires special permission for a private company to run facial recognition software on images to which they have unrestricted license."  [And this type of "Is *X* legal?" question is difficult to answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/414/dealing-with-is-x-illegal-questions).